# POSTGRES SQL JAVA create custom type with a java class

Tags: java, sql, database, postgresql, types

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Connection c = null;
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres", // db
                "postgres", // account
                "ForOnlyOneTick1" // password
        );


        Object loc = Dimension.class;
        PreparedStatement insertNew = c
                .prepareStatement("CREATE TYPE loc AS (?);");
        insertNew.setObject(1, loc);

        insertNew.executeUpdate();
        insertNew.close();

        c.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

In that example i tryed to create a Dimension-type in my database.
But it not work.

It is possible create a column with a particolar type of java class?

or can i use only types that they are knowed by my database ?

for example:

```
CREATE TYPE location AS (x int, y int, z int, name VARCHAR(15));
```

OK, but the problem continue if i need to create a type as:

```
CREATE TYPE land AS (area Dimension, people ListPeople, probability int, cause Causes);
```

Dimension,ListPeople,Causes are my custom-classes with public values other classes.

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to this http://rob.conery.io/2014/11/03/using-custom-types-with-postgres/ you can create a custom type with the existing base types, your custom type will look like your class.

Answer (score 0):

The database knows nothing about Java classes. You will need to explicitly list all the columns when defining the data type.

You can do like this:

```
CREATE TYPE dimension AS (x int, y int);
CREATE TYPE listpeople AS (names text[], etc.);
CREATE TYPE land AS (area dimension, people listpeople, etc.);
```